# How to set Background Image in Content View in Xamarin

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have one ContentView in which i need to set background Image.There is "BackgroundImage" Property for ContentPage,What to do in ContentView?is it possible in xamarin to set background image in ContentView?

Comment: I think you'll need to add an `Image` inside the `Content` of the `ContentView` and use `RelativeLayout` or `AbsoluteLayout` to be able to make it as background.

Comment: Managed to do so by using AbsoluteLayout Thanks!!@PaulKaram

Comment: Glad I was able to help. @Jolly, it would be nice if you posted your own answer and select it as accepted, in order not to leave this question open like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In ContentView use AbsoluteLayout and put Image inside AbsoluteLayout with other controls.It works!!

```
 <ContentView.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Image Source="abc.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
        <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <Grid>
                ......
                ......
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Comment: Where do you have to put image file?

Comment: @alvarogalia In background of ContentView in Xamarin. It's already sorted now.

Comment: This also works to show a backdrop that covers the whole page. Just simply replace Image with a BoxView:
`<BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Color="#4B000000" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" InputTransparent="True" />`